# iOS Safari standalone exception to external navigation

Tags: javascript

I have this code I grabbed somewhere to make my Standalone iOS Web-App stay within itself while navigating in the app:

```
(function(document, navigator, standalone) {
// prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
// this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
    var curnode,
        location = document.location,
        stop = /^(a|html)$/i;
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        curnode = e.target;
        while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
            curnode = curnode.parentNode;
        }
        // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
        // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
        if ('href' in curnode && (curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host)) && e.defaultPrevented !== true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            location.href = curnode.href;
        }
    }, false);
}
})(document, window.navigator, 'standalone');
```

This basically prevents the app from going in background and opening a link in Safari while in the App.

I need an exception to this, so that when I place a target="_blank" or a rel="external" attribute it actually has to open in Safari (and the WEb-App going to background).

I tried placing an if statement before line 15 like this:

```
(function(document, navigator, standalone) {
// prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
// this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
    var curnode,
        location = document.location,
        stop = /^(a|html)$/i;
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        curnode = e.target;
        while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
            curnode = curnode.parentNode;
        }
        if (e.target.getAttribute('rel') == 'external') {
            window.open("http://www.google.com");
        } else {
            // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
            // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
            if ('href' in curnode && (curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host)) && e.defaultPrevented !== true) {
                e.preventDefault();
                location.href = curnode.href;
            }
        }
    }, false);
}
})(document, window.navigator, 'standalone');
```

But does not work...

Comment: You need to use `curnode` not `e.target`

Comment: @chiliNUT what I dumb I've been. Tks a lot

Comment: This does not work in latest iOS/safari. Do you have the same problem? It will execute the location.href but suddenly it leaves the app and opens safari.

Comment: No @nelsonvarela I don&#39;t have it works fine for me

Comment: I've change `location.href = current_node.href;` into `location.assign(current_node.href);` and now it stays inside the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
(function(document, navigator, standalone) {
// prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
// this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
var curnode,
    location = document.location,
    stop = /^(a|html)$/i;
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    curnode = e.target;
    while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
        curnode = curnode.parentNode;
    }
    if (curnode.getAttribute('rel') == 'external') {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    } else {
        // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
        // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
        if ('href' in curnode && (curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host)) && e.defaultPrevented !== true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            location.href = curnode.href;
        }
    }
}, false);
}
})(document, window.navigator, 'standalone');
```